# How to trigger Paste operation in Selenium tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, paste, geckodriver, safaridriver

I tried passing Ctrl + V in /keys but the API is deprecated in newest version of Selenium (v3.4.0)

Webdrivers earlier followed JSONWire Protocol. So to send keys on the focussed element WebdriverIO module used the following route.
`/session/:sessionId/keys`
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#sessionsessionidkeys

The newer versions of webdriver follow the new W3C standard:
https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/

It has `/session/{session id}/element/{element id}/value`
https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-send-keys

But it is not quite that efficient. Key combinations don't work the same way.

Comment: Could you, please, be more specific, which API exactly is deprecated?

Comment: It works fine for ChromeDriver, but fails for GeckoDriver and SafariDriver.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"v"));
```

I see no deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JAVA Robot object which emulates keyboard keys and the String Selection to save the text you want to paste into clipboard.